# Add a variable to request in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In Django I want to add a variable to the request. i.e,

```
def update_name(request):
    names = Employee.objects.filter()
    if names.count() > 0:
        request.update({"names": name })
    return render_to_response('chatlist/newchat.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'form': form,'msg': msg}))
```

Is this the right way to add a variable to the request? If not, how should I do it?

Also, how can I retrieve the same value in the templates page? i.e,

```
alert ("{{request.names['somename']}}");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The example you have given is wrong because

1. there is no request.update function
2. You are using `name` variable which you haven't assigned anywhere?

Anyway, in python you can simply assign attributes, e.g.

```
 def update_name(request):
     names = Employee.objects.filter()
     if(names.count() > 0): 
         request.names = names
 return render_to_response('chatlist/newchat.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'form': form,'msg' : msg}))
```

Also you don't even need to assign to request, why can't you just pass it to template e.g.

```
def update_name(request):
    names = Employee.objects.filter()
     return render_to_response('chatlist/newchat.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'form': form,'msg' : msg, 'names': names}))
```

And in the template page you can access request.name, though if you are doing this just to have a variable available in template page, it is not the best way, you can pass context dict to a template page.

Edit: Also note that before using request in template you need to pass it somehow, it is not available by default see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Answer (score 2):

**Working Code !!**

Assume a variable named my_name. I will add this to **get** and **post** requests.

```
my_name = "Nidhi"
```

To add variable in Get request

```
_mutable = request.GET._mutable
request.GET._mutable = True
request.GET['my_name'] = my_name
```

To add variable in POST request

```
_mutable = request.POST._mutable
request.POST._mutable = True
request.POST['my_name'] = my_name
```

Now here in request there is a variable added name my_name.
To get its value use below code -

```
request.GET.get("my_name")    # get request variable value in GET request
request.GET.get("my_name")    # get request variable value in POST request
```

**Output : Nidhi**

Comment: Not a Django expert by far but whenever I see access of "private" (`_`) members in Python in general I am wondering whether that's the way to do it.